# Why am I getting c# oneshot search exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"?

Tags: c#, search, sdk, splunk

I got this exception lately, and I have no idea why. 2 days ago everything was fine, and I have absolutely no idea what is going on now. 
Now i know this is null exception, but again - don't see why. It appears on "using (var stream = service.Oneshot(oneshotQuery, outArgs))". Neither service.Oneshot isn't null, and outArgs. Only thing that comes to my mind is "stream", but why?

It is not hard to see i am relatively new in c#.

Exception MessageBox shows:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at Splunk.Service.VersionCompare(String right) at
>   Splunk.Service.SetSegmentationDefault(Args& args) at
>   Splunk.Service.Oneshot(String query, Args inputArgs) at
>   Transkrypter_2.0.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:...\Form1.cs:line 45

line 45 is "using (var stream = service.Oneshot(oneshotQuery, outArgs))"

I would be thankful for help with this:

```
 using Splunk;



private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         try
         {
             var connect = new ServiceArgs
             {
                 Host = "myip",
                 Port = 8089,
                 Scheme = "https"
             };

             Splunk.Service service = new Splunk.Service(connect);

             var oneshot = new Splunk.Client.JobArgs();
             //oneshot.EarliestTime = "2015-08-09 10:25:00";
             //oneshot.LatestTime = "2015-08-09 11:25:00"
             String oneshotQuery = "search * | head 10";

             var outArgs = new JobResultsArgs
             {
                 OutputMode = JobResultsArgs.OutputModeEnum.Xml,
                 Count = 0,
             };

             using (var stream = service.Oneshot(oneshotQuery, outArgs))
             {
                 using (var rr = new ResultsReaderXml (stream))
                 {
                     foreach (var @event in rr)
                     {
                         richTextBox1.Text += "Event:" + Environment.NewLine;
                         foreach (string key in @event.Keys)
                         {
                             richTextBox1.Text += "   " + key + " -> " + @event[key];
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }

             button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() ,ex.Message.ToString());
         }
```

Also  I'd like to mention, that this is second application, just to test this error, and here as in my main application same exception occurs.

Comment: I suspect that a member of outArgs has not bee initialized. Can you supply the definition of  the type JobResultArgs?

Comment: The exception is occuring inside the Splunk.Service.Oneshot() method, so without seeing that code it's difficult to provide much help. Are you able to set a breakpoint in that method and step through to see exactly where it fails? That's assuming you have the code for Splunk.Service and it's not a 3rd party dll. If so, are there any properties on the variable 'service' that indicate whether it is connected that you can check since one guess is that the connection isn't being established.

Comment: The definition of JobResultArgs is in [here](http://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/CshrpSDK/1.0/html/292dc974-91ea-8b21-19d6-0f5a04ddf84e.htm) As for the 3rd party dll - using Visual Studio 13 you just have to download NuGets Splunk SDK, and that is what i am using, so it's hard for me to get more info out of it. But i can tell for sure, that connection is stable, because i am trying to figure out each element. I feel silly 'cuz of this question, since it is quite nooby-one, but really no more options left. Been contacting to splunk support, but no answer yet.

Comment: Here's the code guys: https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-csharp/blob/81e7a305b75c70e56475861991945a542692af56/SplunkSDK/Service.cs#L745. Also note that this is the v1 C# SDK. V2 is much cooler and does async. http://dev.splunk.com/csharp

Comment: @NigelK was kinda right. I just forgot to add `service.Login("login", "password");` after `Splunk.Service service = new Splunk.Service(connectArgs);` I've found that alone, but code above just make it more obvious - stupid me. One only remain mystery: how the heck it worked previously... ;) So yeah, topic closed, thanks alot for help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NigelK was kinda right. I just forgot to add `service.Login("login", "password");` after `Splunk.Service service = new Splunk.Service(connectArgs);`
I've found that alone, but @halr9000 code above just make it more obvious - stupid me. One only remain mystery: how the heck it worked previously... ;) So yeah, topic closed, thanks a lot for help everyone!